# Referencing parent(s) of labels

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, packages

I'm trying to reference a label's parent so it outputs something like "Section, Subsection" or "Section, Subsection, Subsubsection". I've come close with `smartref` by doing the following:

```
\usepackage{smartref}
\addtoreflist{section}

\newcommand{\breadref}[1]{\sectionref{#1}, \fullref{#1}}
```

but this unfortunately only outputs the number of the section and not the name of the section. The documentation of `smartref` alludes to a `\byname` option but doesn't seem to actually provide a working example of it, making it difficult to implement.

It seems like this should be an easy thing to do, and a useful thing at that, especially if subsections might move between sections making hard-coded references to parents a pain.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Mike

EDIT:

Ideally, it would look like this:

[image: sketch of desired output]

Comment: I think you want to have a look at `nameref` and `cleveref`.

Comment: @egreg I had a look at these packages but couldn't find what I was looking for. Think you could point me in the right direction or put together an answer?

Comment: Please, add a sketch of the expected output.

Comment: @egreg Added to main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some tweaks!

However, you need to use `\sectionlabel` for sections and `\subsectionlabel` for subsections and not just `\label`, because we need to add functionality.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[byname]{smartref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionlabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newparent{#1}{\@currentsectionlabel}}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand{\sectionlabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}%
  \@bsphack\gdef\@currentsectionlabel{#1}\@esphack
}
\newcommand{\newparent}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{parent@#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\broadref}[1]{%
  \byname{\@nameuse{parent@#1}}, \byname{#1}~(\ref{#1})%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{My section}\sectionlabel{sec:mysection}

Some text.

\subsection{My subsection}\subsectionlabel{subsec:mysubsection}

Some text.

\section{Reference section}

This is a reference to the subsection:
\broadref{subsec:mysubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though I don't really understand what's going on here, it worked perfectly.